# font size within corner.label and bquote in R

Tags: r

No amount of googling has found me the answer, so I'm hoping someone here can tell me.

I'm making a simple x-y scatter plot (actually it's part of a 3x3) with the regression equation displayed above the chart. Currently, I have the r2 value in the upper right hand corner of the chart, but the font is a bit too small. I've tried adding "cex" to every part of the corner.label line below, to no avail. Suggestions.

Basically, how to I get this text to be larger:
corner.label(label=bquote(R^2 == .(rMay15)), x=1,y=1)

[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqR74.jpg)

Thanks,
Pete

```
dev.off()
par(mfrow=c(3,3))    

x <- 1.3 #text size for numbers on axes
z <- 2.0 #text size for labels on axes
y <- .9 #text size for y = mx+b


plot (data$MayKa, data$May15, ylab="May", xlab="", cex.axis=x, cex.lab=z)
lmMay15 <-lm(data$May15~data$MayKa)
rMay15 <- round(summary(lmMay15)$r.squared, digits=2)
corner.label(label=bquote(R^2 == .(rMay15)), x=1,y=1)
summary(lmMay15)$r.squared
abline(lmMay15)
lmMay15 <- round(coef(lmMay15), 2) # extract coefficients 
mtext(bquote(y == .(lmMay15[2])*x + .(lmMay15[1])), 
      adj=0, padj=0, cex=y) # display equation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like they included the option in the function to increase the font size. But, we can easily modify the code to allow for the `cex` parameter to be passed to `text()`. If you use corner.label2, which I have below, you can change the font size.

```
corner.label2 = function (label = NULL, x = -1, y = 1, xoff = NA, yoff = NA, 
          figcorner = FALSE, ...) 
{
  if (is.na(xoff)) 
    xoff <- strwidth("m")/2
  if (is.na(yoff)) 
    yoff <- strheight("m")/2
  par.usr <- par("usr")
  xpos <- par.usr[(3 + x)/2]
  ypos <- par.usr[(3 + y)/2 + 2]
  if (figcorner) {
    par.pin <- par("pin")
    xplotrange <- par.usr[2] - par.usr[1]
    yplotrange <- par.usr[4] - par.usr[3]
    par.mai <- par("mai")
    xmar <- xplotrange * par.mai[3 + x]/par.pin[1]
    ymar <- yplotrange * par.mai[2 + y]/par.pin[2]
    xpos <- xpos + x * xmar
    ypos <- ypos + y * ymar
  }
  if (!is.null(label)) {
    if (figcorner) 
      par(xpd = TRUE)
    text(xpos - x * xoff, ypos - y * yoff, label, adj = c((1 + 
                                                             x)/2, (1 + y)/2), ...)
    if (figcorner) 
      par(xpd = FALSE)
  }
  return(list(x = xpos, y = ypos))
}

plot(1:10, 1:10)
corner.label2("test", cex = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: So do I need to run all of that code for graph (I have 9 in the 3x3) or just once to "create" the corner.label2 command. Or is there a library I have to load to get the corner.label2?

Comment: @Dr.Peat You need to copy the whole function into R, highlight the function and run it, then you can call to it just like you would any other function.